# Google Analytics Benchmarking Reports - "No data for this view"

Tags: google-analytics

Benchmarking is enabled in the Account Settings and has been for some time.

Using the *unfiltered* view, each of the Benchmarking reports (Channels, Locations, Devices) shows "There is no data for this view" where the table should be.

Have you experienced this? What is the reason why no data would be returned in an unfiltered view?

Comment: This is OT (not code related), but to enable benchmarking you need to click the "Benchmarking" checkbox in the account's data sharing settings.

Comment: I can confirm that Data Sharing is enabled in the Benchmarking section of the Account.

Comment: Using a CMS with baked-in GA.js. Do not have access to modify. Thus is the answer though.

Comment: Ups, sorry, messed up again. I confused demographics and benchmarking. Per documentation benchmarking should not require displayfeatures to be active.